# What do the Power/Technique/Graffiti stats mean?

Tags: jet-set-radio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do Power, Technique, and Graffiti stats do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85938/what-do-power-technique-and-graffiti-stats-do)

In Jet Set Radio for Vita I've got 3 characters with slightly different stats. I don't really know what they mean. I assumed Technique meant the character is easier to control and Graffiti meant either large graffiti is easier to cover up or they could carry more spray paint cans. From a small amount of personal testing I can't really tell the difference between the three starting characters. I also have zero idea what "Power" would mean unless it's health.

What do the character stats mean?

Comment: @cloudymusic how did...I hate that suggestion box

Comment: It happens to everyone! :P